# css loading in certain devices only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi i'm building a website with wordpress
its only a splash page for now.

the website is http://www.polymathco.com

im on a desktop mac and it displays fine, on my laptop it displays fine.
but on my iphone and ipad the css doesnt load. (it did a few days ago)

ive tried adobe browserlab and in all tests the css doesnt load.
i tried opening via a proxy site -snip- on my imac and the css doesnt load.

ive cleared my cache and cookies and it looks fine on my imac and mbp. could this be something to do with the .htaccess on the server?

the css url is generated by wordpress , (bloginfo(template_url)) and it loads fine in my desktop.

Comment: btw i tried on safari chrome and firefox. displayed consistently on my desktop and laptop.

Comment: Your CSS is pointing to `http://localhost/` ...?! Is your blog URL set up correctly in the settings?

Comment: I see this in Safari: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/polymathco/wordpress/wp-content/themes/polymath/css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" type="text/css">

Comment: yes i somehow transfered my local mirror db of the site to the remote server. weird. fixed it via some sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site seems to be looking for the css file in /polymathco/wordpress/wp-content/themes/polymath/css/style.css

When it actually appears to be in /wordpress/wp-content/themes/polymath/css/style.css

Use bloginfo('stylesheet_url') for the css file, and check your admin panel settings(under general) to make sure your site's path is set correctly.

Comment: got it. it only loaded on my desktop and laptop because the localhost reference referred to my local mamp folder with a mirrored test environment.

Comment: and i must have somehow my database the other way around, local to remote. the url and home entries referred to localhost on my local machine. thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

In your admin panel, click Settings, and in General, make sure the 'WordPress address (URL)' and 'Site address (URL)' are set to your actual site, rather than localhost.

Comment: couldnt do it this way because i couldnt get to the wp-admin due to the url mistake in the database, it kept pointing to my localhost. had to do it via SQL and changed the entries manually